# orderBy title, but remove the word "The" from titles

Tags: entry, ordering, filtering

If I have a huge list of TV shows and Movies, many of them have "The" in the title, meaning they all get grouped together if you order by title.

Is it possible to "filter out" a word in entry titles when using orderBy?

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('media').orderby('title asc').limit(24).all() %}
```

Comment: This seems to be answered over here -> https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/29996/526

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

`` {% set entries = craft.entries().section('media').orderBy("(CASE WHEN `title` LIKE 'The %' THEN SUBSTRING(`title`, 5) WHEN `title` LIKE 'A %' THEN SUBSTRING(`title`, 3) ELSE `title` END) asc").limit(24).all() %} ``
worked.

Comment: Really cleaver!